# Size of a symmetry group for segments of lines

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If we have three disjoint lines of equal length in the place, and they are labeled AB, CD and EF. What is the size of the group of symmetries of this configuration as a group acting on the endpoints? Exchanging line segments or flipping segments end for end is legal.

So there are $3$ flips we can perform, and there are $3$ exchanges we can perform. Then would the size of the group just be $|G|=3\cdot 3 = 9$?

Comment: Aren't there $3!$ permutations of the three lines? Then the symmetry group would be the wreath product $\Bbb Z_2\wr S_3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we represent the line-segments by their endpoints then we can write $[1,2], [3,4]$ and $[5,6]$ for them. An exchange between the two first segments can then be represeneted by $a = (1,3)(2,4)$, likewise for the two other exchanges $b = (3,5)(4,6)$ and $c=(1,5)(2,6)$, the only thing that is missing in the group is the flip $d = (1,2)$. We don't care about the other flips since they can be represented as $d^a$ and $d^c$. Now the total group with generators $[a,b,c,d]$ takes the form $C_2 \times S_4$ and has size $48$.